# I can't connect to my virtual router (apparently I'm typing the incorrect password?)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router

Okay, so I've tried to set up a virtual router using these:

- virtualrouter.codeplex.com/
- virtualrouterplus.com
- virtual-router.net/

And others like it. None of them worked however, and my phone would be "unable to connect to the network" with no other error given. I then read about creating a virtual router from within the CMD (http://lifehacker.com/turn-a-windows-8-1-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-the-com-1593327340) and did the steps mentioned. However when I try to connect, it says that I am inputting the wrong password. It's not user error, as I have tried multiple times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=VirtualRouter key=123456789 (For the key you type in what you want it to be.)

That goes in CMD, make sure that the internet is disconnected before you do this.

After typing that command you are going to want to type this one and just hit enter:
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

edit: This is for http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/  (If it matters)

Comment: So I just disconnect my internet, do the command, then start the virtual router?

Comment: Yep, that should do the trick! If not, report results and I'll have something else for ya c:

Comment: I did [this](http://gyazo.com/8be3862cdef2762102a1c315296866c0) and [this](http://gyazo.com/0b725f79ab9c503d44e28f994ff8a16b) exactly like you said, but no luck.

Comment: I apologize but I forgot to add that second command. :c

"After typing that command you are going to want to type this one and just hit enter: netsh wlan start hostednetwork"

Comment: I've done that before, but not in conjunction with the VirtualRouter program. Will it make a difference?

Comment: I did it so I have [this](http://gyazo.com/89098110adc5090b80140c34e57e75cc) and [this](http://gyazo.com/c8a105c48eddbbbd4d90460bb937e501) but nothing changed in regards to the password. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: Worth a shot, not sure to be completely honest.  Have you made sure that your original connection is sharing the connection through the VirtualRouter as well?  Sometimes it can show up as not working even though you actually have an access point!  So open up google to test for yourself, don't just base it off of what you see down on the tray.

Comment: I shared my connection with my main one.

Comment: Hmm, never had this problem before.  I guess double check to make sure that the box for  "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection" is indeed checked.  Aside from that I'm not sure why the password isn't working correctly.  _Strange_

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your wlan adapter is compatible with the hostednetwork?  You can check by entering **netsh wlan show drivers**.  Look through the results and hopefully you find **"Hosted network supported: Yes"**

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your wifi adapter wireless mode to G mode.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPhNQ.jpg

Answer (score -1):

ssid must be same as computer name, password must be same as computer password.
after changes above mine started to work.

Comment: "ssid must be same as computer name" - This statement is false.